# Dependency and condition oder in azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

In Azure pipeline yaml file, when defining multiple jobs in a single stage, one can specify dependencies between them. One can also specify the conditions under which each job runs.

Code #1

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - script: echo hello

- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  steps:
  - script: echo this only runs for master
```

Code #2

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - script: "echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent;isOutput=true]false"
    name: printvar

- job: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(dependencies.A.outputs['printvar.skipsubsequent'], 'true'))
  dependsOn: A
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from B
```

**Question:**

Code #1 & #2 above have different orders of the dependency and condition. Does the order matters? If so, what's matter? (what's the difference between different orders)

Comment: I don't think the order matters. The dependsOn determines WHEN the job starts. The condition determines whether or not the job runs at all. What is the context of the question? Do you run into any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Discuss 1 and 2 separately.*

**Code #1**:

Since there is no data connection between `job1` and `job2`, data connection here refers to *variable sharing* and etc.

So, for #1, there's no matters on order. Here you can ignore the `dependsOn` specified  while you have no special requirements on the execution order between `job A` and `job B`.

BUT, there's one key thing you need pay attention is, the actual running order will be changed randomly when you do not specify the `dependsOn`. For example, most of time, they will respect with the order `job A`, `job B`. Occasionally, they will randomly run as `job B`, `job A`.

**Code #2**:

This must make the `dependsOn` specified. Because your `job B` is using the output variable which created/generated at `job A`. Since our system allow same variables name exists in different jobs, you must specify the `dependsOn` so that the system can know the `job B` should find the variable `skipsubsequent` from `job A` not others. Only this key words specified, the variables which generated in `job A` can be exposed and available to next jobs.

So, the nutshell is once there is any data connection between jobs, e.g variable pass, you must specify `dependsOn` to make the jobs has connection with each other.